# Convert character date to formatted date

Tags: date, sas

I have the following dataset, where the values in `date` are of the general format `<character d>mmyy`:

```
DATA df;
INPUT date $;
DATALINES;
d0101
d0102
d0103
d0104
;
RUN;
```

I want each row in `df` to turn into the following (numeric/date type):

```
01JAN2018
02JAN2018
03JAN2018
04JAN2018
```

Here's my attempt:

```
DATA df_new;
    SET df;

    FORMAT date DATE9.;

    date = INPUT(SUBSTR(date, 2, 2) || PUT(INPUT(SUBSTR(date, 4, 2), 8.), MONNAME3.) || PUT(YEAR(TODAY()), 4.), DATE9.);
RUN;
```

However, this just gives me the following:

```
21185
21185
21185
21185
```

How can I complete this conversion?

Comment: That was covered in the previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084364/sas-iterate-from-beginning-to-end-date-in-a-macro, you didn't include the format statement which was in the answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like below using mdy function and applying date9. format once you create date from mdy function, which can take month day and year to make a date

> ```
> DATA df;
> INPUT date $;
> DATALINES;
>  d0101
>  d0102
> d0103
> d0104
> ;
> RUN;
> ```

```
data want;
  set df;
   new_date=mdy(input(substr(date,2,2),2.), input(substr(date,4,2),2.), year(today()));
  format new_date date9.;
run;
```

you can also use

```
 new_date=mdy(substr(date,2,2), substr(date,4,2), year(today()));
```

but it will have following message in your log

```
  NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places 
  given by: (Line):(Column).
```

Answer (score 2):

You are applying a format, but the **date** variable still contains numeric value (number of days since SAS Epoch). 
You are also incorrectly reusing the **date** variable. In the **df** dataset it is created as character, in **df_new** you are writing a numeric value to it. So to fix it, change **date** to **dateN** in the **df_new** dataset. And finally to convert it to character, you need to perform one more step:

```
...
dateN = input(substr(date, 2, 2) || put(input(substr(date, 4, 2), 8.), monName3.) || put(year(today()), 4.), date9.);
length dateC $9;
dateC = put(dateN, date9.)
...
```

Comment: What do you mean "you are also incorrectly reusing the `date` variable"?

Comment: It depends on the situation, but in SAS you usually do not want to overwrite a character variable with numeric values and vice versa. Although SAS will automatically covert it, it is easy to make a mistake in this case. As a result you are applying 'DATE9.' format, which is a numeric format, to a character variable and that is why you see integer numbers (as a string) instead of formatted dates. Still even if you see formatted dates, the actual raw value is always numeric. That is why the conversion step using PUT was needed.

Comment: It is probably a lot easier to use a different informat that going to such trouble to convert numeric (looking) month number into abbreviated month name instead.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is identical to the one I answered in your other question.

There is **no need** to extract the numeric aspects within a string with a presumed construct `d<mm><dd>` for feeding into `MDY`.  Instead, flesh out the string representation of a date, and use `input` with a date informat to establish the SAS date value (which is simply a number representing the number of days since the SAS date epoch, which is 01JAN1960).  SAS date values are rendered according to a format. If left unformatted, you will see only an integer.  Formatting the variable as `date9.` will cause output to render the appropriate `<dd><mon><yyyy>`, or format `yymmdd10.` which will render as `<yyyy>-<mm>-<dd>`

```
date_value = input (cats(year(today()), substr(date,2)), yymmdd10.);
format date_value date9.;
```

or more explicitly

```
year_string = cats(year(today());
mmdd_string = substr(date,2);
yyyymmdd_string = cats(year_string,mmdd_string);
date_value = input(yyyymmdd_string, yymmdd10.);
format date_value date9.;
```

If you absolutely need to (unlikely) store the date, rendered as a string, back in the original date variable, you would have to use `put` to force the rendering at value assignment time.

```
date = put(date_value, date9.);
```